# how can i use sonar with hector_mapping package (laser and IMU) to draw map?

Tags: navigation, mapping, sonar, hector, hector-mapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i created /map with laser an imu by hector_mapping package. but how can i use sonar (with laser and imu) too create better map?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64608/how-can-i-use-sonar-with-hector_mapping-package-(laser-and-imu)-to-draw-map?/) by [Mohsen Hk](https://answers.ros.org/users/4097/mohsen-hk/) on ROS Answers with karma: 139 on 2013-06-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It's non-trivial to improve LIDAR based maps using sonar sensors, as they return only one very noisy measurement for a cone in front of the sensor. There is no ready to use ROS package for sonar mapping available AFAIK.

/edit: So what is relatively easy to do is just using the pose provided by the SLAM system and following a "mapping with known poses" approach, building a independent map in parallel that incorporates LIDAR and sonar data. This would avoid the issue of the SLAM map degrading from noisy sonar data and allow to create a better map in the sense that for instance glass could be detected via sonar.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-06-10

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [parzival](https://answers.ros.org/users/35453/parzival/) on 2021-01-03**:
But won't sonar be helpful to detect glass?

**Comment by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) on 2021-01-15**:
True, I edited the answer to discuss this aspect.